# Not able to change VS Code Font Family

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am fairly new to VScode, I wanted to add **Ubuntu Mono** Font in VScode. I downloaded the file from Google Fonts page. I extracted and Installed all the different Styles that were available. Here is a photo of the downloaded fonts that I had installed.
[image]

Then to verify whether the font was installed or not I opened a word file where I could select **Ubuntu Mono**. On Stackoverflow I came across 2 methods of Changing the Font family, either editing the settings.json file or using the GUI in VScode by writing the Font family name. I am attaching my modified settings.json file here [image]

I tried other options as well like:

```
   "editor.fontfamily":" 'UbuntuMono-Regular', monospace"
   "editor.fontfamily":" 'UbuntuMono-Bold', monospace"
   "editor.fontfamily":" 'Ubuntu Mono' , monospace"

   //here I tried to play around with spaces:
   "editor.fontfamily":" ' UbuntuMono ', monospace"
```

but whatever I do it is showing the same default monospace font. Any Guidance Regarding this will be helpful. My VScode is updated(It shows March 2021 (Version 1.55)) If any more information or Screenshots are required please let me know.

Comment: did you restart VSC, you need to use the name as shown by the font viewer

Comment: @rioV8 I did restart multiple times but to no use, as you can see in the question above I tried different names as well for the font family.

Comment: you do not try which name is correct, you use the font viewer to see what is the correct name to use, the name is also in the file and can be different from the file name. Never have an argument with font designers about names.

Comment: @rioV8 Well first of all there is no argument going on, Second, if I knew that I am correct then there would be no point in asking my question here, third I did check it with whatfont and fontviewer both, it is **Ubuntu Mono** .

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I tried it with the OTF version: `UbuntuMono-Regular.otf`

Install the font.

The following settings worked.

```
"editor.fontFamily": "'Ubuntu Mono', monospace"
```

You have to **RESTART** VSC

Comment: Thank you, This worked when I restarted VScode for the third time.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I am inputing the font name incorrectly,
e.g. I input

```
'Delugia Mono Regular'
```

but in fact vscode does not need `Regular` cause it accepts font **family** as input, changing it to:

```
'Delugia Mono'
```

and it worked.

**No need to restart or even save the settings file**, the change would appear in 1 second after you've entered a legal fontfamily as input.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable all installed extensions from vscode and edit the .json file again, choose your font and make sure that it has been installed then save all changes

[image: See how to disable vscode extensions here]

Comment: Another option it's replace vs code to emacs

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else finding this that ran into the same quirk as me: note that if you have entered an invalid font then the setting is not saved. So the editor will not use a fallback font if it was entered at the same time as the invalid font.